# Heroku pipelines without github

Tags: git, heroku

I am trying out heroku `pipelines`. I would like to have a `staging` and `production` pipe.  I have created both pipes in heroku console. And my push is set to go to `staging` . But I do not see any `promote` to production option in the console. The documentation focus on integration with github.

I would like my pushes to go to `staging` then once i tested it promote it to `production` without github.

Comment: Have you figured out how to proceed ? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku pipelines:promote -r staging
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines#promoting

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an app for each stage, eg. app-staging and app-production.

The apps can be created from the same git repo or from different branches depending on your workflow.

So, create a pipeline, add the app-staging to your staging stage, the app-production to your production stage and the promote option will appear.

Comment: I am doing exactly what you suggest, two different apps from the same repo. Production is the master branch and Dev is new branch but when I add the app (hence the branched code) to the dev stage it doesn't reflect changes of this branch... any idea?